# Enclose string in quotes if special character present

Tags: perl

I'm trying to accomplish special character handling in a single line command. Issue: If string has the special character (§), then enclose entire string in quotes.

```
Input : FTN§NS
Expected Output : 'FTN§NS'
```

I tried below, but I'm not getting the expected output.

```
perl -p -i -e "~ s/[§]/\'/g" file
```

---

```
Output : FNT''NS
Expected : 'FNT§NS'
```

Comment: `perl -p -i -e "s/.*§.*/'$&'/" file`

Comment: Thak you for your response . It resolve the problem.

Comment: should really be: `perl -p -i -e "s/.*§.*/'\$&'/" file` to ensure shell doesn't try to perform substitution on the `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```perl
s/^.*§.*/'$&'/;
```

or

```perl
$_ = "'$_'" if /§/;
```

In a sh shell, you could use

```bash
perl -i -pe's/^.*§.*/\x27$&\x27/' file
```

or

```bash
perl -i -pe'$_ = "\x27$_\x27" if /§/' file
```

`"\x27"` produces a single-quote.